# SNMP client error when authentication with MD5 algorithm

Tags: c++, snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

The Ubuntu SNMP client worked correctly with SHA authentication, but failed with MD5.

`Error: Authentication failure (incorrect password, community or key)`

snmpd.conf:
sysServices 72
master agentx
agentaddress udp:161
view systemonly include .1.3.6.1.2.1
rocommunity password default -V systemonly
createuser user MD5 v3_authphrase
rouser v3_authphrase authNoPriv -V systemonly

The command executed to receive data from the client is as follows:
`snmpwalk -u user -l authnopriv -a MD5 -A v3_authphrase localhost`

Comment: Did you manually modify `snmpd.conf`? Please revert the lines you added and instead use `net-snmp-create-v3-user` https://linux.die.net/man/1/net-snmp-create-v3-user

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @LexLi net-snmp-create-v3-user dosnt add user to /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf. Therfore `snmpwalk` failed to retrieve client information

Comment: You made a few wrong assumptions. First, `net-snmp-create-v3-user` inserts user credentials to the proper destination that can be picked up by `snmpd` (the agent), not necessarily `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`. Second, `snmpwalk` does not retrieve user credentials from any conf file either, but from the command line arguments. Try `net-snmp-create-v3-user -A authentication -a MD5 authNoPriv` (stop/start `snmpd` is needed) and `snmpwalk -v 3 -l authNoPriv -a MD5 -A authentication -u authNoPriv localhost 1.3.6.1.2.1.1` and that should give you a starting point.

Comment: @LexLi  tried the exact command:
first `net-snmp-create-v3-user -A v3AuthPhrase -a MD5 md5AuthUser`  
`restart snmpd service`  
`snmpwalk -v 3 -l md5AuthUser -a MD5 -A v3AuthPhrase -u md5AuthUser localhost 1.3.6.1.2.1.1`  
the result is: `snmpwalk: Unknown user name`

Comment: `net-snmp-create-v3-user` should have told you which conf file it modified. Edit your question to include the contents of that file. Besides, `-l` for `snmpwalk` must be `authNoPriv` and you shouldn't change it. Read the manpage and learn what each switches means.

Comment: @LexLi sorry, it was typing mistake. `-l authNoPriv` is correct